SSH public key authentication fails for root user with debug error 51 on AlmaLinux 9
I am trying to connect to a remote SSH server as the root account, using public keys.  The login fails and ssh reports:
debug1: Will attempt key: mykey.pem  explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password

and the server error log reports only:
Sep 22 12:13:21 remotehost1 sshd[67019]: Connection closed by authenticating user root 172.31.254.31 port 42192 [preauth]

The '51' response seems to be generic something wrong with key/security/permissions/file/etc.  So login fails and I'm prompted for a password.  On the client:

the private key file is valid (including LF at end)
the private key is in pem format
the private key file has 600 permission
the .ssh directory has 700 permission
the key file and .ssh directory are owned by root:root

On the server:

The sshd config contains:
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys


The authorized_keys file has 600 permission

The authorized_keys file has a LF at the end

I have restarted the sshd service to pickup changes

I ensured selinux context is correct for authorized_keys
chcon -t ssh_home_t /root/.ssh/authorized_keys


I set selinux into permissive mode


In case it matters, the sshd is running on AlmaLinux 9.

I stumbled upon the answer.  The private and public keys on the CLIENT did not match.   By running
ssh-keygen -y -e -f myprivatekey.pem

and comparing the output to mypublickey, I found there was a difference.  Another clue was that ssh-copy-id refused to copy the public key (just said file not found).  In both cases the cause was a private vs public key mismatch.
